# Mapping Marker objects to storable Data objects

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle the separation of Marker object from a custom object that contains the data and can be stored in a fragment when the Activity is destroyed.

I want to:

1. Show the position several moving entities on the map.
2. Store the data of each entity when onDestroy() is called.
3. Show additional information about a selected entity on a sidebar

.

For each position I create a marker stored on a HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, Marker> markers;

private Marker createNewMarker(String sourceName) {
   Marker marker;
   marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
      .position(new LatLng(0, 0)));
   marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
      .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_sys));
   markers.put(sourceName, marker);
   return marker;
}
```

When I receive information through the network about the entity I update the marker:

```
private Fragment dataFrag;
private final Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // Message has both an unique id and a name that will change
    // Update the data in the Fragment 
    // Update marker fields
 }
```

When the marker is clicked information about it will appear in the sidebar

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // Identify what entity the markers refers to
    // Marker only has the name (which changes) in the title
    // HELP HERE!!!
    // Update labels
    return true;
});
});
```

I don't know a O(1) approach to find the entity based only on the name (and without the id).
Can I store additional values in a Marker?
Should I extend the Marker class and add another field?
What is the best approach?

I had to separate Marker from entity data so that I can store the data in a Fragment without storing the markers.

All help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Each marker gets a new and unique ID assigned, when it is created.
Instead of adding "hidden" data directly into the marker, just keep a map, which maps the ID of the marker to the additional data.

In your case this may be a map similar to your markers-map but organized in an inverse manner:

```
markerToSourceMap.put(marker.getId(), sourceName);
```

In onMarkerClick you can retrieve the sourceName by

```
sourceName = markerToSourceMap.get(marker.getId());
```